# Bash shebang is ignored - script is still executed with zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, shebang

I have a script on Mac OSX which is executed when opening a new terminal. It is specified in `.zprofile`. It has a bash shebang but it is still executed with zsh (my default shell). What may be the problem here?

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The core problem is that I am not able to execute the script due to differences of zsh syntax. When I analysed what may cause this, I recognised that the shebang is just ignored.

I have a binary /bin/bash btw.

Edit:

`~/.zprofile` executes the script like so:

```
. ~/.script.bash
```

Comment: As per the `bash` [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) on `SHELL`, `If it is not set when the shell starts, Bash assigns to it the full pathname of the current user’s login shell.` So, just because `/bin/zsh` is echoed doesn't mean it's `zsh` executing the script. How are you executing the script in `.zprofile`?

Comment: @cody True. I just set the shell of my terminal to something different (but kept zsh as default) and $SHELL is still zsh even though bash is actually used this time. I'll add the execution bits of the script to the question.

Comment: @cody I edited the question to address the actual issue leaving out the $SHELL portion.

Comment: CVers - This is not a typo; typos are unintentional mistakes that would not be repeated should OP try to re-type the same thing more carefully. This is intentionally written the way it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have written in you `~/.zprofile` the following line:

```
. ~/.script.bash
```

This is similar to

```
source ~/.script.bash
```

Which implies that your script is sourced and not executed. You should have something like:

```
~/.script.bash
```

instead which will execute in the environment defined by the shebang. Note that the file needs to be executable.

> **`. file [ arg ... ]`:** Read commands from `file` and execute them in the **current** shell environment.
>
> **<sub>source: `man zshall`</sub>**

Comment: The flip side of this is that if the script *does* need to be sourced (sets shell or environment variables for the current session), then it needs to be written in `zsh`, not `bash`, and the shebang is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

When you "source" a script file (i.e. `. <script-file-name>`) the commands in the file are executed in the current shell, using the syntax of the current shell.  Any "shebang" line in the file is interpreted as a shell comment and is ignored.

If the shell commands in your script file can be run by executing the file, you can make it an executable file and run it as a command.

However when you execute a shell script, the execution happens in a child process.  That means that things that need to alter the state of the current shell / process won't work.  Things like:

- changing this shell's environment variables
- defining this shell's functions or aliases
- changing this shell's working directory
- changing this shell's ulimits
- and so on

If you need to do that kind of thing, you have no alternative but to translate your `bash` script into a `zsh` script so that you can "source" it in `zsh`.